# Slow Navigate + Component Inefficient Delayed Loading

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I'm building a disconnected (i.e. no data sources) canvas app that models a multi step form (10 steps, split across two screens). I'm running into some performance issues on Navigate to the screens which is puzzling since there is no remote data to fetch (there is some usage of SaveData/LoadData).

For context, I use components heavily in the app to help with consistent behavior and styling.

[image: Sample Component]

The only clue i have right now is that there are a lot of "Inefficient Delay Loading" warnings, basically one for every instance of a component in the app. These warnings don't make sense to me since the screens don't refer to each other's controls and only share state via Navigation Context and Collections (no cross screen control references). 
[image: Delayed Loading warnings]

Any ideas on what could be causing the Navigate slowness or if the delayed loading warnings are valid (i.e. they are not an artifact of components being new)? The OnVisible of the screens isn't doing much at all.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed lately that performance is very sluggish in the PowerApps EDITOR (maker-facing) but actually manageable in the PLAYER (user-facing). Are you seeing perf issues in the Player?

Comment: Performance is definitely better in the PLAYER, but still bad enough that users can sometimes see the Disabed on Press styling for 2-5 seconds.

Comment: Yeah, this is recently happening for me as well.